# sending data between two computers on different network(over the internet)

Tags: java, http, networking

hey i have a java swing application on one computer A(at work site) which takes some data. Now i want to send the data to another computer B(at my office).following are some ideas i thought of to solve this problem:-

1)Host a server in computer B using java netty & wrap the data taken from the computer A as a Http request which can be sent to B. But i'll need to know the IP address of computer B which is in different network. So the problem is how to get the ip address of B. Now suppose i know the ip address what is the guarantee that A will send the data to B coz since B is in different network there may be some other computer with same ip address in computer A's network

2)I can have a mysql databse in computer B & use the remote access feature to send datafrom swing application in computer A directly to the databse in cmputer B. But i am not sure whether i can access mysql databse remotely from computer within the same network or any computer anywhere in the world.

any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since the computers are on different networks than you should go with option one. I'd suggest taking a look at sockets in java and how they work. please see links below:

[java sockets](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077322/core-java/sockets-programming-in-java-a-tutorial.html)
[oracle docs java sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/)

Comment: but then how do i solve the ip address problem i.e. how do i know the ip address of computer B before sending the Http Request

Comment: you can bind the socket using the server name not the server ip. that might solve your problem.

Comment: what do you mean by server name & not ip. In a network every computer is identified by it's IP address ri8?. can you please elaborate